# How to add my CSS class to form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I newbie in drupal 7. I am writing new theme and I don't know how to add my class to form in drupal 7. I install ubercart to setup e-commerce website. I added new attribute for product (Size). I want to redesign in product page. In this page, It has size field but I don't know how to add my CSS. E.g:

```
<form action="/drupal-7.34/node/6" method="post" id="uc-product-add-to-cart-form-6" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div id="uc_product_add_to_cart_form-6-attributes" class="attributes"><div class="attribute attribute-1 odd"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-attributes-1">
  <label for="edit-attributes-1">Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <select id="edit-attributes-1" name="attributes[1]" class="form-select required"><option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option><option value="1">39</option><option value="2">40</option><option value="3">41</option></select>
</div>
</div></div><input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-w06CKx7aNBiYShqfg8LiP98CaFLpEb8mgWzFYQWqnQ4">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="JtZIrcKeIfXiVpwX43K6KqHPlZazR1klS1ht3W7PI9I">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="uc_product_add_to_cart_form_6">
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input class="node-add-to-cart form-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit-6" name="op" value="Add to cart"></div></div></form>
```

I want to add my class to the `select` element. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to include your CSS in the page or how to add another class to the element after including your CSS?

Comment: I want to add my CSS in the page

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory there is file named theme_name.info . Inside of it there should be (or you can create it) array that defines css file which will be included on page. Check out explanation here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/171205

https://www.drupal.org/node/171209

So, you basically have to add path of your css file to that list and it will be included on every site page. Your html.php template must print out stylesheets variable (which will contain paths to css files). If you are not sure how to do it check how it's done on some standard drupal theme that comes with drupal installation.

After adding your css to theme info file don't forget to clear the cache!

Other way would be to include it manually, from page.tpl.php file. Just add there common CSS include line, like you would that in plain HTML file.

You can add CSS even from code with drupal_add_css() function, but that's a bit more advanced.

And you can use form id attribute to "aim" it and all inner elements with css.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to create new theme, but I want to ask how to add my CSS for specific element. I create new attribute named `Size` for `Product`, and in product page it display like above. I want to add my CSS to element `select`. How can I do that?

Comment: form#uc-product-add-to-cart-form-6 input#edit-attributes-1 {css}

Comment: Drupal gives id's to every element, so just check page html (as you did), check element id and use it to target desired element.

Comment: But it only change style for the `product 6`. It not affect to other product

Comment: Can you "hit it" by aiming some outside (wrapper) element?